# Elixir GenServer handle_call callback return type

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am implementing a GenServer and I am confused.

I know `handle_cast` is asynchronous, which means the caller is not waiting for a reply and we return a tuple like this: `{:noreply, new_state}`.

I have noticed that we can also return the same tuple from `handle_call`. Does it mean if I have a `handle_call` that returns `{:noreply, new_state}`, it wont return anything but will be synchronous? The flow of the caller will wait on the `GenServer.call` command, and then continue after the `handle_call` function has completed?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this article: https://medium.com/@derek.kraan2/elixir-tip-noreply-is-a-killer-feature-40d7d803b272

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The caller will block waiting for a reply `whenever` you invoke GenServer.call. The reason for `handle_call` to accept `{:noreply, state}` as a valid return is to allow you to [reply/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#reply/2) manually (from any place).

The calling process will block waiting for a `reply` (and timeout according to your settings, etc), just the same.

The second argument to the `handle_callback` is a `from` reference, as in `handle_call(msg, from, state)`, that can then be used with `reply/2`.